# How to get Video in Youtube API from Firebase when using it within RecyclerView and cardView

Tags: android, firebase, youtube, android-recyclerview, youtube-api

I am using **Youtube** API in my application with **firebase** as a database but for some reasons my Youtube player is **not getting the video** from firebase, when I use it with **CardView** and **RecyclerView**. If I place my Youtube Player in cardview it does not even show in application, Please help.

> I am using Android Studio

Comment: post your firebase DB structure and error log

Comment: @akhilesh0707 there is no error, and i am posting it

Comment: @akhilesh0707 done sir, please check

Comment: you need to pass only YouTube VideoID not complete URL

Comment: In your case your id is `Q7e0rWEn` pass the only id remove `https://www.youtube.com/` from db field

Comment: @akhilesh0707 i have also tried that but the player is not visible in the application, is it because of cardView?

Comment: did you get record from firebase?  what is the value of `model.getYoutubing()` add log or debug and check what values you get from firebase

Comment: try to pass hardcode value on `youTubePlayer.cueVideo("hardcodeVideoId");`

Comment: @akhilesh0707 no sir, hard coded video ID also did not work

Comment: @akhilesh0707 do i have to add a layout manager or something?

Comment: instead of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter try with Custom RecylverView Adapter

Comment: @akhilesh0707 sir actually i am new to android so can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: try this link https://androidtutorialmagic.wordpress.com/my-mini-project/multiple-youtube-video-in-recyclerviewlistview-in-android/

Comment: @akhilesh0707 sorry for late reply, but brother i need to get data from firebase database, how i will do so by using custom adapter for recyclerView

Comment: Did you create custom adapter?

Comment: @akhilesh0707 the above link was not helpful for adapter with firebase, so i was unable to create it, please help

Comment: @akhilesh0707 can you please help me sir, i am stuck here

Comment: Sure but give me some time right know I’m not on machine I will answer here

Comment: Thanks in advance sir

Comment: did you add your key on `youPlay.initialize("SOME KEY"`

Comment: @akhilesh0707  yes sir i had

Comment: @akhilesh0707 sir when will you help me, i am still stuck